# Reverse sentence duplicate removal

Tags: java

I need to remove "the enter a sentence to be reversed" bit at the top and the bottom, because it shouldn't be there. Below is my code and the console message that needs to be fixed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ques1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence;

        do {
            String newsent = "";

            System.out.println("\nEnter a sentence to be reversed: ");
            sentence = scanner.nextLine();
            for (int i = sentence.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                newsent = newsent + sentence.charAt(i);
            }

            System.out.print(newsent);

        } while (!sentence.equals("exit"));
    }
}
```

> Enter a sentence to be reversed: (**want to remove this**)
>
> Enter a sentence to be reversed:
>   Hi how are you?
>   ?uoy era woh iH
>   Enter a sentence to be reversed:
>   I am doing great, thanks.
>   .sknaht ,taerg gniod ma I
>   Enter a sentence to be reversed:
>   Exit
>   tix
>   Enter a sentence to be reversed: (**Want to remove this**)

Comment: Either your posted code is incomplete or your output doesn't match the output your could would generate. Btw, your abort word is `exit`, not `Exit`.

Comment: Dude, just move that line outside the do-while!

Answer (score 0):

Your input is wrong and it doesn't match with the string check "exit". The loop will continue till you feed the input as "exit".